# Curious case of asymptotic equivalence

Tags: asymptotics

Let us consider $n$ a positive integer and $F(n)$ an increasing function of $n$.

What conditions $F$ should fulfil to obtain the following:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F(n)}{F(n-1)} = 1$$

?

It appears that this is wrong if $F(n)=exp(n)$.

Are there general results about this ?

Thank you.

Comment: The statement is true for all polynomials, for example.

Comment: @5xum Thank you for your comment. Are we able to say something for other types of function?

Comment: If $g(n)$ satisfies it, then $g(n)P(n)$ satisfies it, where $P(n)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: You also have the trivial case of $F$ bounded, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}F(n)$ exists.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment as a contribution, is that I believe that you could be interested in Theorem 8, from Jakimczuk, *Functions of Slow Increase and Integer Sequences*, Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 13 (2010), Article 10.1.1. It is an open access journal.

Comment: Thank you for your link.

Comment: @Dingo13 I know that this journal is very good. Enjoy it!